# replacement of multiple characters in a single element of xml using XSL

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

i am replacing &#10 with br tag to show new line while transforming xml using xsl. i                want to replace blank spaces to its according code that may &nbsp or something else at the    same time.sample code is below. please suggest for me what should i do.

while xml file may be as ------------

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?><?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl"     
href="task.xsl"?><Nodes><sNode><Word><![CDATA[1
2.............3............4............5
 3]]></Word></sNode></Nodes>
```

since blank spaces ommitted automatically so here ........ represents blank spaces.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <table>
           <xsl:for-each select="Nodes/sNode">
              <tr>
                 <td>
                    <xsl:call-template name="replace-string-with-element">
                       <xsl:with-param name="text" select="Word"/>
                       <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="'&#10;'"/>
                       <xsl:with-param name="with" select="'br'"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                 </td>
                </tr>
             </xsl:for-each>
          </table>
       </body>
    </html>
 </xsl:template>



<xsl:template name="replace-string-with-element">
  <xsl:param name="text"/>
  <xsl:param name="replace"/>
  <xsl:param name="with"/>
  <xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="contains($text,$replace)">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,$replace)"/>
        <xsl:element name="{$with}"/>
        <xsl:call-template name="replace-string-with-element">
           <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text,$replace)"/>
           <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$replace"/>
           <xsl:with-param name="with" select="$with"/>

        </xsl:call-template>
     </xsl:when>
     <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
       </xsl:otherwise>
     </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `xsl:character-map` as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" exclude-result-prefixes="fn xs">

    <xsl:character-map name="replaceChars">
        <xsl:output-character character="&#10;" string="br"/>
    </xsl:character-map>

    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" use-character-maps="replaceChars" indent="yes"/>

    <!-- Implement your templates -->   
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It is even possible to save all characters in a `xsl:character-map` in an external XSLT and use `<xsl:import href="characterFile.xslt" />`

---

To implement this in your stylesheet use the following XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:character-map name="replaceChars">
        <xsl:output-character character="&#10;" string="br"/>
    </xsl:character-map>
    <xsl:output method="html"  use-character-maps="replaceChars"/>

   <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <table>
           <xsl:for-each select="Nodes/sNode">
              <tr>
                 <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="Word" />
                 </td>
                </tr>
             </xsl:for-each>
          </table>
       </body>
    </html>
 </xsl:template>
```